# how to group several sizes in one row shopping cart magento

Tags: shopping-cart, product

someone can help me. please, i need group the sizes of configurable products in one row in the shopping cart

something like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzVNu.png

Comment: thanks for answering. I am some new to magento. I tried to modify the files

app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml

app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

In the cycle where data weapon, achievement but still not get it to work is complicated. 

Can you help me ? you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: sorry, I've never used magento before but these details will help others come up with an answer